# Why in Spanish localization TimePickerDialog, "A.M." will shown as "A."?

Tags: android

We use `TimePickerDialog`

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
            hourOfDay, minute, false);
```

However, if we were in Spanish localization

[image]

---

The **A.M.** will displayed as **A.**

[image]

---

May I know why it is so? How can we fix it?

I'm testing using Android 9.

### Update

An issue tracker is submitted - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137524644

Comment: have you checked both on emulator and on a device? Is it the same in both?

Comment: I tested in my phone (pixel phone), emulator and based on feedback from a native Spanish user, all yields this behavior.

Comment: this is a very interesting question haha

Comment: Also happens on a Nexus 5X w/ API 28.